# Create a smooth repeat/loop a video?

Tags: loop, smooth

I'm new to Blender and I've been trying to do this thing for a few days now, been googling and youtube and saw a lot of videos but I still just couldn't find a solution yet :(

Hope I'll be able to explain this good enough but I'm trying to make a video of 30 seconds (field with a lot of flowers moving by the wind a little bit) to repeat itself, which I was able to pull off

but the issue that I'm having is that I need it to look smooth, like I need the video to keep playing for 5mins as if it was really 5mins and not 30 seconds, but everytime I tried to do that, such as copy + paste the 30 secs vid, or Backspace to remove all gaps, right after the first vid (30 secs) the video quickly froze/and cut out, as well as the audio for like 1 second or even less actually, which was something quite noticeable, and I know it's 100% possible somehow because I've seen many videos like that

So the question is, how do I make a video of 30 seconds and turn it into a 5mins video as if it was really 5mins with no cutting/freezes, etc? =O

Comment: does it freeze when you render it or just when you preview it? Because it may freeze when you preview but the render should work fine

Comment: I also think you cannot assume that the preview playback is always as smooth as the final render. I often had problems with video playback in Blender (no matter what tips I followed for prefetching and all that kind of stuff) although my hardware should have been capable of doing that (at least it was good enough with DaVinci Resolve). But if you do not want to render a 5 minute video to see if the result is smooth, just make it 1 minute. Another possibility: is the last image the same as the first so it looks like freezing? Is the audio completely filling all frames without any silence?